# Prevent chrome autosuggest list

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm using a bootstrap date-picker and with a recent update to Chrome, it started super-imposing a suggestion dropdown on top of the date-picker like this:

[image: Covered Date Picker]

I've tried the

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

and

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

suggestions for disabling auto-fill, but neither worked. Mind you, there is no autofill happening, it's only the suggestion list that is popping up and only after clicking on the input, so I don't know if this would even be governed by `autocomplete`.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this to each input field that you have:

```
role="presentation" autocomplete="nope"
```

For me it works. Tested on Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Perfect! worked for the new popups for street addresses and zip codes on Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100

Answer (score 3):

Adding autocomplete="off" attribute will disable autocomplete for an input that isn't a username or password field

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)
Note: This link states that turning off autocomplete breaks [WCAG 1.3.5](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/identify-input-purpose.html) but I'm not sure that is entirely true. Going to discuss with them.

Answer (score -1):

Workaround :

```
$('#Name').on('mouseup keyup', function () {
            var val = $('#Name').val();
            val = val.length;
            if (val === 0) {
                $('#Name').attr('autocomplete', 'on');
            }
            else {
                $('#Name').attr('autocomplete', 'new-password');
            }
        }).on('mousedown keydown', function () {
            var val = $('#Name').val();
            var length = val.length;
            if (!length) {
                $('#Name').attr('autocomplete', 'new-password');
            }
        })
```